# Regex - Match substring with Strings

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have 2 Dataframes, What I am trying to achieve to to create a list of the IDs that match. With this information I can then perform a merge later on (The merge isn't part of my question, I just want to find out how to match the rows correctly).

**DF1**

| ID |
| --- |
| 123 |
| 123B |
| 234 |
| 234B |
| 456 |
| 456B |
| asfdh5 |
| 45gh |

**DF2**

| ID |
| --- |
| 123456 |
| 123B456 |
| BBBER4 |
| 234567YT |
| B9234BAA |
| 456XXA32 |
| 999GHF |
| pp9985 |
| 88AVKVBD |

**Desired Result** - I want to get a list of string that match

|  | Matches |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 123 |
| 1 | 123B |
| 2 | NaN |
| 3 | 234 |
| 4 | 234B |
| 5 | 456 |
| 6 | NaN |
| 7 | NaN |
| 8 | NaN |

The current code I am using is the following

`df2['ID'].str.extract(fr"({'|'.join(df1['ID'].values)})", expand=False)`

The issue is that this code doesn't match the IDs in DF1 exactly, if you see for index 2 in **Desired Results** above the result is **123B**, However I'm only getting 123.

Below are the results I'm getting with my current code.

|  | Matches |
| --- | --- |
| 0 | 123 |
| 1 | 123 |
| 2 | NaN |
| 3 | 234 |
| 4 | 234 |
| 5 | 456 |
| 6 | NaN |
| 7 | NaN |
| 8 | NaN |

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanking you,
Cian

Comment: @DSteman correct, and for Index 4 it should be 234B etc. Whereas with my code I'm only getting 123 and 234(I'm missing the B in some instances)

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that it checks from the top of DF1 when it looks for a match and returns the first match. If you sort the dataframe by the length of the strings in the column it returns the longest match instead.

This should fix your problem:

```
# Sort by length of string
new_index = df1.ID.str.len().sort_values().index
df1 = df1.reindex(index = new_index[::-1]).reset_index(drop=True)

# Match strings
df2['ID'].str.extract(fr"({'|'.join(df1['ID'].values)})", expand=False)
```

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is expected because "For each subject string in the Series, extract groups from the first match of regular expression pat." (https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html). So you're getting '123' instead of '123B' because '123' is the first value in the series in `df1`, and hence the first match.

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is to sort your `df1['ID']` values by length in descending order using `sorted(df1['ID'].values, key=len, reverse=True)`:

```py
>>> df2['ID'].str.extract(fr"({'|'.join(sorted(df1['ID'].values, key=len, reverse=True))})", expand=False)
0     123
1    123B
2     NaN
3     234
4    234B
5     456
6     NaN
7     NaN
8     NaN
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

You need this because longer alternative in NFA regex engines (Python's `re` is) always "wins" and all the other alternatives in the same group are not even tried by the regex engine. See [*Remember That The Regex Engine Is Eager*](https://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html#eager). E,g. you hd `123|123B` in your regex, so `123` matched `123` in `123B456` and returned that match, `123B` alternative was not tried, and so on.

Comment: thank you. When I try to perform a merge using the data from above (I called it key in my code) I get a key error. Would you know why this is?   ```df1 = pd.merge(df1, df2[['Name', 'Company']], left_on=['ID'], 
#              right_on=[key], how='left').drop_duplicates().fillna('') ```  Please note that DF2 also has a column containing company information which I am trying to merge into DF1

Comment: @PythonBeginner Let's deal with the questions one by one. If the above solves the problem, please let know. This follow-up question can only be answered once you provide all the data, and it should be a separate question.